# create new data frame by merging it with reference data in a better way compared to for loop

Tags: r

I have more than 500 files (df1) in a folder and i want to create a new files by merging it with a reference table (nf1).

```
data[1] <- Composite.REF Call Confidence
          SNP_A-2131660    2     0.0053
          SNP_A-1967418    2     0.0075
          SNP_A-1969580    2     0.0042
          SNP_A-4263484    2     0.0052
nf1 <- 
    Composite.REF   dbSNP.RS.ID Chromosome      Physical.Position Allele.A  Allele.B   Gene    region
        SNP_A-2131660   rs4147951       2           66943738           A         G        ABCA8   intron 
        SNP_A-1967418   rs2022235       2           14326088           C         T        ---     downstream 
        SNP_A-1969580   rs6425720       2           31709555           A         G        NKAIN1  intron 
        SNP_A-4263484   rs12997193      2           106584554          A         C        ---     upstream 

finalFile <-

        Composite.REF   dbSNP.RS.ID Chromosome      Physical.Position Allele.A  Allele.B   Gene    region    data[1]
         SNP_A-1969580   rs6425720       2           31709555           A         G        NKAIN1  intron      0.042




listFiles <- list.files(pattern = "data.txt$",recursive=T)  # list all the files with extension data.txt

    for (i in 1:length(listFiles)){
        data<-read.table(file=paste(listFiles[i]), sep="\t", skip=1, header=T)
        dataF <-data[data$Confidence < 0.05,] #add a filter
        finalFile <- merge(dataF, nf1, by = "Composite.Element.REF") #merge 2 data based on common column
        write.table(finalFile, gsub("data.txt", "data_new.txt" ,listFiles[i]), sep = "\t", row.names=F, quote=F)   #save the output
        }
```

This takes a lots of time in complete as it loops though one sample at a time. i want to know if there are more elegant for the job.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code to see what is the slowest part of the job? If it's the `read.table` line you may want to try `data.table::fread`

Comment: read.table and fread takes almost the same time. Is there any way to execute it in parallel for all the 500 files  rather than looping through it each file at time?

Comment: You could use the `plyr` package to load all the data into one combined data frame, merge that with the reference once, and then save out chunks of the big data frame into separate files. See `adply()` and `d_ply()`.

Comment: @jdobres could you please show how to use plyr on the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely difficult to answer this question without some data, but the *plyr* package would allow you to do something like this:

```
library(plyr)

data.main <- adply(listFiles, 1, read.table, sep="\t", skip=1, header=T) # load all files
data.main <- subset(data.main, Confidence < 0.05) # reduce data by cutoff value
data.main <- merge(data.main, nf1, by = 'Composite.Element.REF') # merge data sets

# write out all files
d_ply(data.main, .(.id), function(x) {
    file.name <- sprintf('new data %i.txt', listFiles[x$.id[1]])
    write.table(x, file.name, sep = "\t", row.names=F, quote=F)   #save the output
})
```